# Can mysqlimport take a directory instead of file as input?

Tags: mysql, shell

I have a big table file which are split into multiple smaller files in a directory. Is it possible to let mysqlimport to take a directory of files as one parameter?

```
mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 ...
```

Edited:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/abigail/output/bword/split

for f in *.txt
echo "Is loading the file $f now ..."
do

    mysql -u linga -p --execute="use wordDS; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$f' INTO TABLE Term FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (terms_id); SHOW WARNINGS"
done
```

This almost works, except that it complains this line:

echo "Is loading the file $f now ..."

```
/home/abigail/scripts/loadData.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'                                                                                                                                                         
/home/abigail/scripts/loadData.sh: line 6: `echo "Is loading the file $f now ..."'
```

Comment: Are you running Linux or Windows?

Comment: [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538995/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-a-mysql-database) may be helpful to you.  One option would be to use a batch script.

Comment: The `echo` needs to be inside the `do` block, not where it is, but I don't understand why you haven't tried your question title for yourself, or looked up the documentation, or what the shell script you posted has to do with the title of your question.

Comment: Through Tim I learnt that mysqlimport can not take a directory as an argument and do the job. Instead, I have to use a script to iterate trough each file in a directory, and that is the solution to my question.

Comment: So it's an answer, not a question.