# Is there a way to use a WHILE and IF/ELSE statement in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

So, a little background.  I have a 3.7gb CSV file that is to big for my computer to handle.  So I used a handy little program to split it.  It split it evenly into about 4,000 smaller CSV files so my computer could import them without freezing.  Each file is labelled the exact same, with the except of the last 4 characters being different as they ate incrementimg numbers from 0 to whatever the last one is.

So, my overall question is: Is there a way I can import these with a loop instead of manually importing each one or bulk importing them all at once?  I'm still fairly new to SQL and am running mysql workbench on a Linux machine.

Thank you!

Comment: Might be some valid options already listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538995/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-a-mysql-database  or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/57830/inserting-all-csv-files-into-a-table-in-mysql

Comment: Control flow statements like WHILE and IF/ELSE are supported only in MySQL stored programs; outside of that context, WHILE is not a valid "SQL" statement. And its unlikely that a MySQL stored procedure would be a good fit for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say what DBMS you're using nor how you're importing, but it's likely that you can use a WHILE loop to accomplish what you need.

```
WHILE expression DO
   statements
END WHILE
```

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-loop.aspx