# Ingest multiple excel files to MySQL using query

Tags: mysql, excel

I am trying to load data from excel files into a table in MySql. There are 400 excel files in .xlsx format.

I have successfully ingested one file into the table but the problem is that involves manually converting excel file into a csv file, saving it on a location and then running a query to load using `LOAD LOCAL INFILE`. How to do it for rest of the files.

How to load all the 400 .xlsx files in a folder without converting them manually to .csv files and then running the ingestion query one by one on them.Is there a way in MySql to do that. For example, any FOR Loop that goes through all the files and ingest them in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Try bulk converting your XLSXs into CSVs using [in2csv](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html) as found in [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

```
## single file
in2csv file.xlsx > file.csv

## multiple files
for file in *.xlsx; do in2csv $file > $file.csv; done
```

Then import data into MySQL using `LOAD LOCAL INFILE...`

From loading multiple CSVs, use `for file in *.csv; do...` or see [How to Import Multiple csv files into a MySQL Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538995/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-into-a-mysql-database).